# If $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function then does this hold?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f$ is differentiable infinite number of times, then there exist $x\in (0,1)$ such that

$$\frac{f(1)-f(x)}{x}=f'(x)$$.

I have tried to use Lagranges Mean Value Theorem .

It lands me with $f(1)-f'(x)=(1-x)f'(x+\theta(1-x))$ where $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Then I thought that I could differentiate both sides again and again to get some form of $\theta^{n}$ but to no avail.

Even the differential equation $xf'(x)+f(x)=f(1)$ admits a solution but I don't think that it will help me.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed with this?

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable only on the open interval? If $f$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$ then this is a trivial application of MVT to the function $xf(x)$.

Comment: It was not mentioned explicitly where it was differentiable. So I assumed it to be differentiable over the entire Real Line . But I don't think that that will affect the result. If it is even $C^{\infty}[0,1]$. I think that the result should hold. But I cannot seem to begin where or how to start the proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can assume without loss of generality that $f(1)=0$. Now let $g(x) = x f(x)$. We have $g(0)=g(1)=0$. Hence there is a point $c$ in $(0,1)$ where $g'(c) = 0$. It follows that $c f'(c) + f(c) = 0$, QED.

More generally if $\alpha>0$ and we choose $g(x)=x^\alpha (f(x)-f(1))$, the same argument applies, we have $g(0)=g(1)=0$ and there is a point $c\in (0, 1)$ such that $\alpha c^{\alpha-1}(f(c)-f(1))+ c^\alpha f'(c)=0$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
f'(c) = \alpha \frac{f(1)-f(c)}{c}
\end{equation}

Comment: Oh my god. It was so simple. I even found a particular solution to the differential equation to be $xf(x)-xf(1)=1$. I should have figured it out from there. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Counter-example $f(x)=\frac  1x$ when $f$ is only $C^{\infty}$ on $(0,1)$.

If $f$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$ then this is a trivial application of MVT to the function $xf(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on @Gribouillis's solution.

Take $g(x)=xf(x)-xf(1)$ . Then $g(0)=g(1)=0$.

Then there exist $c\in(0,1)$ such that $g'(c)=0$.

$g'(c)=f(c)+cf'(c)-f(1)=0\implies \frac{f(1)-f(c)}{c}=f'(c)$ . Thus you have your answer. And yes for the intuition regarding this, the solution of the ode was a good observation.

Comment: Have you noticed there is also a $c$ such that $f'(c) = 2022 \frac{f(1)-f(c)}{c}$ ?

Comment: Yeah I saw your comment. Keen observation. I think the original question could have entailed that to make it more interseting . @Gribouillis You should maybe edit that in your already great answer. I have upvoted it.

Comment: @Gribouillis: your comment will be even more pertinent in two weeks.